# Sharepoint Roles configuration

Tags: roles

When you install a sharepoint 2010, do you have to add Web Server (IIS) and application role manually or it is automatically installed when you do "Install software prerequisites"?

Answer (score 2):

It is automatically configured by the prerequisites installer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to John's - the Prerequisites are only properly installed on Windows Server (2008 or 2012). If however you install SharePoint 2010 on the client (e.g. Windows 7 or Windows 8) you would need to install and configure prerequisites by yourself, and that includes manually downloading and installing them all from web, and configuring your OS by installing required Windows components.

There are many alternative to help you, most based on PowerShell, starting with the excellent Autoinstaller on CodePlex or some scripts available on MSDN Gallery (e.g. http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/bcf3332d-f726-4ac7-b01a-eeda4b7ece8e).

Comment: I have to vouch for AutoSPInstaller, it's an amazing superscript that I use often for deployments!